# How to secure a $_GET

Tags: php, sql, get

I am working on a Wordpress site and there is a feature we need that doesn't exist exactly the way we need it. Without creating a whole membership site we need to email users weekly emails with links to a dynamic page where they will be able to access the number of audio files based on their week (drip campaign). The emails don't come from Wordpress, they come from a CRM.

So: http://website.com/audiodownloadpage/?xyz=1 (they will be able to access one audio), http://website.com/audiodownloadpage/?xyz=2 (they will be able to access two audios) etc. etc.

This is the variable call using $_GET:

```
$abc = isset( $_GET[ 'xyz' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'xyz' ] : '';
```

I put the variable in the query_posts() function so it know how many to display.

I tried to add:

```
addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags()))
```

on recommendation of another thread on SO, but it broke the page. I think I'm doing it wrong. Could someone show me how to get the same variable with the protections in place? It's for one page and a closed audience, so I risked using this method and I would like to protect it as much as I can.

Comment: what are you going to do with value?

Comment: USE PDO! http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers, 
That's the ONLY way to be reasonably safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: Using prepared statements with placeholders are the *only* way of protecting the user input, whichever API prefere - `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: "...on recommendation of another thread on SO" what thread is that? So I can digitally punch whoever said that in the face.

Comment: Is this being used in SQL? Show the usage of `$abc`. `$_GET` can be insecure in XSS injections as well.

Comment: really its noting to do with $_GET any user input from nay source needs to be sanatised if its going to be used in a query. But if that's the case the best approach will depend on what api your db connection use. there's no one size fits all function here

Answer (score 0):

To protect the value when inserting it in database, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you are using mysql. But I would not recommend using it as it's deprecated and removed from PHP's latest version. A better choice would be: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

If you want to use the value on a web page, you may want to protect it for XSS attack. In that case, use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) or [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) functions.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, I think this might be closest to what I need, yes I am using it for a web page. I'll try it and check back.

Comment: Welcome @semidivine. If it helped, accept my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about securing a database against an SQL injection you may want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: link only answers are discouraged